# GeoServer WMS service CQL filter query with Mapbox GL

Tags: wms, query, cql-filter, mapbox-gl-js

Is there any way to query WMS tile layer for [Mapbox GL](https://www.mapbox.com/help/define-mapbox-gl/)?

```
map.addLayer({
    'id': 'wms-test-layer',
    'type': 'raster',
    'source': {
        'type': 'raster',
        'tiles': [
            'https://geodata.state.nj.us/imagerywms/Natural2015?bbox={bbox-epsg-3857}&format=image/png&service=WMS&version=1.1.1&request=GetMap&srs=EPSG:3857&width=256&height=256&layers=Natural2015'
        ],
        'tileSize': 256
    },
    'paint': {}
}, 'aeroway-taxiway');
```

and query like this ??

```
"filter": ["==", "icon", symbol]
```

Leaflet example:

```
var layer = L.tileLayer.betterWms('localserver/geoserver/geoserverlayer/wms?', {
    layers: '',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    version: '1.1.0',
    CQL_FILTER:'department_id like something',
    proxy:'',
    proxyParamName:'url'
}).addTo(map_pa);
```

Comment: The example service `geodata.state.nj.us/imagerywms/Natural2015` does not seem to be be provided by GeoServer software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution just pass the parameter in URL it will return the WMS image (png) of that particular query...

```
http://yourserder:8080/geoserver/VectorTileLayer/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&cql_filter=circle_n=circle name&request=GetMap&layers=VectorTileLayer:table name&styles=&bbox=bounding boxof your desire&width=768&height=492&srs=EPSG:4326&format=image%2Fpng&transparent=true&
```

Find help from this URL

`http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html#cql-filter`